# Solr Query to filter with Regex?

Tags: regex, solr, filter

In Solr, we normally use `fq` keyword to further "filter" the results, like:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=book&fq=title:(xxxx)
```

But, how do i query with filter; for whether the field `title` contains **numbers in it** or not? How about applying **regex** here? *(how to?)*

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear to me what you want to achieve. Can you elaborate a bit more editing your question?

Comment: Its clear enough. To use the `regex` search for the `title` field.

Comment: Ok, if you say so, hope someone else understands and helps you! Cheers

Comment: Does something like this not answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557550/solr-regex-in-filter-query ?